# Changing Application Dock Icon javaFX programmatically

Tags: macos, javafx

I have a javaFX Application that will only load from a JAR however I wanted to change the icon in the mac dock. I have managed to working it out on windows. I am using Netbeans IDE, and would prefer to not add the additional apple JAR Extension file. It is because of this I’m  not sure if it is possible.

Comment: Are you directly using a `runnable jar` or packaging the jar for platform specific runnable files ?

Answer (score 10):

So far I haven't seen a way to do this with JavaFX but there is a way to do it with Apple-specific Java APIs:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        URL iconURL = Main.class.getResource("ui/resources/Logo@2x.png");
        Image image = new ImageIcon(iconURL).getImage();
        com.apple.eawt.Application.getApplication().setDockIconImage(image);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Won't work on Windows or Linux.
    }

    launch(args);
}
```

This works at least with Oracle Java 1.7.0_40 and 1.8.0_25.

The downside is that when you start the JAR, you'll see the Java logo in the dock for a short time which then changes to your icon. This is a technical limitation and can only be worked around by creating a real, native OS X bundle.

Comment: Just checking in 5 years later to see if JavaFX created a better way.  Do you know anything?

Comment: This no longer works since on new versions of MacOS and Java the com.apple.eawt.Application no longer exists

Comment: @Hasen it exists, but it's not exported by the java.desktop module.

Comment: @Juraj Martinka So how can you make it work then?

Comment: @Hasen you need to export the package, e.g. to an unnamed module: `--add-exports=java.desktop/com.apple.eawt=ALL-UNNAMED` (JVM startup option)

Comment: Actually, I think I found a better way. There's a public API for this and that this java.awt.Taskbar#setIconImage - see https://diarium.usal.es/pmgallardo/2020/01/05/how-to-set-dock-icon-of-java-application/