# Can you catch a "package x does not exist" error in Java?

Tags: java, windows, macos, javafx, error-handling

I'm using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27567693/4356188) to set the macOS dock icon of my JavaFX app:

```
try {
    // Sets macOS dock icon:
    com.apple.eawt.Application.getApplication().setDockIconImage(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(appIcon, null));
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Doesn’t work on Windows and Linux
}
```

I can't run the app on Windows because it throws the error "java: package com.apple.eawt does not exist"

How can I catch a "package x does not exist" error or check if it exists at runtime?

Comment: Reflection can catch this

Comment: Put `Class.forName("com.apple.eawt.Application");` at the start of your try-block, and catch ClassNotFoundException or ReflectiveOperationException.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't - it's a compiler error, you can't catch those at runtime. But the notion of 'can I run this code if the class is there, but not run it otherwise' - yeah you can do that, you just have to use reflection, which basically turns compile time stuff into runtime stuff:

```
public boolean trySetMacOsDockIcon(Image img) {
  try {
   Class<?> c = Class.forName("com.apple.eawt.Application");
   Method m = c.getMethod("getApplication");
   Object application = m.invoke(null);
   m = application.getClass().getMethod("setDockIconImage", Image.class);
   m.invoke(application, img);
   return true;
  } catch (Exception e) {
   return false;
  }
}
```

you may want to log those exceptions, at least until you tested this once or twice.

`m.invoke(null)` invokes the method; the first argument is the 'receiver' (the thing to the left of the dot); for static methods, there is no receiver and the parameter doesn't do anything. `getApplication` is static, so we pass null there. The second `invoke` line is an instance method on apple's Application class, so there we do need to pass in a value, namely, the application object we got by invoking `getApplication`. The second parameter there is simply the params for that method, so, we pass the image.

Comment: You can also catch the linker errors in java at runtime (catching a subtype of Error). This does of course require that the compile actually worked. But most likely using reflective access is more flexible as it would allow the code to compile with less dependencies (but you still need to platform offering the package to actually test it, so it’s always a good idea to be careful using that stuff). It is always good to have a fallback solution for when you run it on a different platform.

Answer (score 5):

You could try to find out what your current OS is beforehand. There are basically two ways. Either `System.getProperty("os.name")` or `SystemUtils.OS_NAME` from Apache Commons Lang.

See also: https://www.baeldung.com/java-detect-os